# How to display common pages in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I'm very confuse on how to load my header.php to all the other pages I made. I want my header to be included on every page I made without manually putting them so that every time I make changes to the header I won't edit the entire page. Instead I'll just make changes in the header.php. Thank You.

Comment: You can try loading your header.php inside the view instead of loading it in every functions in your controller.

Comment: But my header contains a toggled menu that has active links. Is it possible that every time I click a menu the active link clicked changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a common page call `layout.php`

inside that

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?> //site header

<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?> //comes from controller. 

<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?> //site footer
```

and in controller

```
function privacy_policy() 
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'pages/privacy_policy';
    $this->load->view('layout', $data);
}
```

and **`main_content`** should direct to page

so its

1. reduce your time
2. reduce your code
3. easy to understand
4. etc....

Comment: @KaelJasper did you check this??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder for example -Layout under view folder and add your common pages like header,footer in it.

And in your controller on calling you can do so-

```
function index() {
        $this->data['survey'] = $this->survey_model->get_survey();
        $this->data['main_content'] = $this->controller . '/show';


        $this->load->view('layouts/main_content', $this->data);
    }
```

In this case **show** is my view page to be displayed,**main_content** is a page in my layout where header and footer is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but the one I prefer the most is as below :

in your Controller File

**SomeController.php**

```
function someFunction() {
        $this->data['main_page'] = 'someview';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main_template', $this->data);
}
```

In your **main_template.php** view

```
<?php 
    $this->load->view('layouts/header');  // your common  header file
    // your dynamic  page file you can choose which page to load by changing the value of $main_page in controller.    
    $this->load->view($main_page);        
    $this->load->view('layouts/footer');  // your common  footer file
?>
```